# What does this '()' notation mean?

Tags: function, f#, value-type, unit-type

I just started to learn F#. The book uses the following notation:

```
let name() = 3
name()
```

what that differs from this:

```
let name = 3
name
```

?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before answering what `()` is lets get some basics defined and some examples done.

In F# a [let statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233238.aspx) has a name, zero or more arguments, and an expression.

To keep this simple we will go with:
If there are no arguments then the let statement is a [value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233185.aspx).
If there are arguments then the let statement is a [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229.aspx).

For a value, the result of the expression is evaluated only once and bound to the identifier; it is immutable.
For a function, the expression is evaluated each time the function is called.

So this **value**

```
let a = System.DateTime.Now;;
```

will always have the time when it is first evaluated or later invoked, i.e.

```
a;;
val it : System.DateTime = 1/10/2017 8:16:16 AM ...  
a;;
val it : System.DateTime = 1/10/2017 8:16:16 AM ...  
a;;
val it : System.DateTime = 1/10/2017 8:16:16 AM ...
```

and this **function**

```
let b () = System.DateTime.Now;;
```

will always have a new time each time it is evaluated, i.e.

```
b ();;
val it : System.DateTime = 1/10/2017 8:18:41 AM ...  
b ();;
val it : System.DateTime = 1/10/2017 8:18:49 AM ...  
b ();;
val it : System.DateTime = 1/10/2017 8:20:32 AM ...
```

Now to explain what `()` means. Notice that `System.DateTime.Now` needs no arguments to work.

> How do we create a function when the expression needs no arguments?

Every argument has to have a type, so F# has the [unit type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/unit-type) for functions that need no arguments and the only value for the unit type is `()`.

So this is a function with one argument `x` of type `int`

```
let c x = x + 1;;
```

and this is a function with one argument `()` of type `unit`

```
let b () = System.DateTime.Now;;
```

Comment: Simply put, its just a F# form of call functions without parameters?

Comment: @Fabricio Yes. But I have add something to get past the 15 character minimum for a comment.

Comment: @Fabricio: I wouldn't say that. `b` here is a function that takes *one* parameter: `unit`. If you try to call it without the parentheses, you get the *function value* `b` rather than the `b` function's *result*. Try `let d = b;; d();;` in FSI.

Comment: Of additional interest: [The Algebra of Algebraic Data Types](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/)

Answer (score 11):

Definitely do NOT think of `()` as some syntax for a function call or anything like that.  It's just a value, like 3, 5, 'q', false, or "blah".  It happens to be a value of type `Unit`, and in fact it's the *only* value of type unit, but really that's beside the point.  `()` here is *just* a value.  I can't stress that enough.

First consider

```
let name x = 3
```

What's this?  This just defines a function on x, where x can be any type.  In C# that would be:

```
int Name<T>(T x) 
{
    return 3;
}
```

Now if we look at `let name () = 3` (and I somewhat recommend putting that extra space there, so it makes `()` look more a value than some syntactic structure) then in C# you can think of it as something like (pseudocode)

```
int Name<T>(T x) where T == Unit  //since "()" is the only possible value of Unit
{
    return 3;
}
```

or, more simply

```
int Name(Unit x)
{
    return 3;
}
```

So we see that all `let name () = 3` is, the definition of a function that takes a `Unit` argument, and returns 3, just like the C# version above.

However if we look at `let name = 3` then that's just a variable definition, just like `var name = 3` in C#.

Answer (score 8):

In

```
let name() = 3
name()
```

`name` is a function, of type `unit -> int`.

In

```
let name = 3
name
```

`name` is an integer, of type `int`.

In F#, every function has an input type and an output type. The input type of `let name() = 3` is `unit`, which has only one value `()`. Its output type is `int`, which has values from `–2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`. As another example type `bool` has only two values, `true` and `false`.

So back to you question what's the usage of `()`. If you don't specify the input value of a function, it cannot get executed. So you have to specify an input value to your function `let name()=3` to get it executed and because of its input type is `unit`, the only value you can use is `()`.

Here is another way to define the name function:

```
let name : (unit -> int)  = (fun _ -> 3);;
```

and compare this to:

```
let name : int = 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `()` creates a function which takes a paramter of type `unit`, rather than the second case which is just a simple integer.

This is particularly important when you want to control execution of the function.

The main difference is when you have

```
let name() = 
    printfn "hello"
    1
```

vs

```
let name = 
    printfn "hello"
    1
```

then

```
let t = name + name
```

will print "hello" once.  But

```
let t = (name()) + (name())
```

will print "hello" twice.

You have to be careful with this when considering the order in which functions are evaluated.

Consider the following program:

```
let intversion = 
    printfn "creating integer constant"
    1

printfn "integer created"

let funcversion() =
    printfn "executing function"
    1

printfn "function created"

let a = intversion + intversion
printfn "integer calculation done"
let b = (funcversion()) + (funcveriosn())
printfn "function calculation done"
```

This will print the following in order

1. creating integer constant
2. integer created
3. function created
4. integer calculation done
5. executing function
6. executing function
7. function calculation done

Comment: I think I need more examples. Its not too clear why its so important yet. Anyway, what is that `;1` for?

Comment: I will add some more examples.  The `;1` us equivalent to a newline and then a 1 so that there is a return value.  I just put it in for brevity

Comment: I don't got why `"creating integer constant"` is printed if it is just defined.

Comment: oh.. is it part of the scope so that it is executed along `intversion` definition although `intversion` will just store `1`?

Comment: @Fabricio this is correct - to store 1 in intversion, the compile has to run any commands preceeding the `1`, which might have side effects before it gets to the 1.