# Why can an argument for the ICommand.Execute method be ignored?

Tags: f#

**Why is an argument not required for the following statement?**

```
viewModel.Submit.Execute()
```

Is the argument an implicit unit type?

**The signature for ICommand.Execute is the following:**

```
/// <summary>
///     Defines the method that should be executed when the command is executed.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parameter">A parameter that may be used in executing the command. This parameter may be ignored by some implementations.</param>
void Execute(object parameter);
```

**Note the last comment on the summary:**

> This parameter may be ignored by some implementations.

**The following DelegateCommand implementation is as follows:**

```
module UILogic.Interaction

open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Input
open System.ComponentModel

type DelegateCommand (action:(obj -> unit), canExecute:(obj -> bool)) =
    let event = new DelegateEvent<EventHandler>()
    interface ICommand with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member this.CanExecuteChanged = event.Publish
        member this.CanExecute arg = canExecute(arg)
        member this.Execute arg = action(arg)
```

**The client to this command is as follows:**

```
// Setup
let viewModel = ViewModel()
viewModel.FirstName <- "Scott"
viewModel.LastName <- "Nimrod"

// Test
viewModel.Submit.Execute()
```

In conclusion, I just don't understand how an argument NOT marked optional can still be ignored in F#.

Any explanation on why this can occur?

Comment: `()` is a value in (of type `unit`) in F# too ... it will be translated into `null`

Comment: Ohhh... Okay. I will give you credit if you'd like to post this as the answer.

Comment: Also take a look at [What does this '()' notation mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17870937/1243762)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`()` is a value in (of type `unit`) in F# too ... it will be translated into `null`

you can try this if you want:

```
> ();;
val it : unit = ()
> box ();;
val it : obj
= null
```