# Defining F# function but not calling it, function still seems to get called

Tags: f#

On the following code, why is the function `printStatement` called ?

```
module Tests

let printStatement =
    printfn "%s" "statement"

let functionCallingPrintStatement =
    printStatement

let functionNotCallingPrintStatement =
    printfn "%s" "This is a test"
```

If I call `functionNotCallingPrintStatement` in my main program?

```
open Tests

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    functionNotCallingPrintStatement     
    0
```

Here is the output:

> statement
>
> This is a test

If I change the function `functionNotCallingPrintStatement` to :

```
let functionNotCallingPrintStatement =
    ()
```

The first statement is suppressed.

Comment: `let printStatement` is a value not a function. `let printStatement()` is a function. See: [What does this '()' notation mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870937/what-does-this-notation-mean/17872004#17872004)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not functions, they are values of type `unit`

```
val functionNotCallingPrintStatement : unit = ()
```

To make them `unit -> unit` functions, add brackets

```
let functionNotCallingPrintStatement () =
    printfn "%s" "This is a test"

val functionNotCallingPrintStatement : unit -> unit
```

Comment: Ok so if I do not use the parantheses (), I am not binding a function into my value. But why is then calling this value from main also printing "statement" ?

Comment: @Lastwall You are binding a value (not a function) to `functionNotCallingPrintStatement` identifier. This value is a result of calling `printfn`, which means `printfn` will be called when `let` is evaluated.

Comment: @Lastwall The starting source for `why is then calling this value from main also printing "statement"` is found in the [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/3.1/FSharpSpec-3.1-final.pdf) Section 12.5, but it will not immediately help you as it is very technical. However you should read it and take the time (weeks to months) to understand it. It will make you a much better programmer.