# How can I link a label to a mutable variable in F#?

Tags: f#, mutable

I want to create a label in F# which uses a mutable variable to return a value. Unfortunately F# sets this label to a constant value. If the value of the mutable changes, the value of the label remains. Isn't it a bit inconsistent? Is there a way to get the label ("a") being dependent of the mutable ("x")?

```
let mutable x = 0;

let a = x + 2; // I want not to set a to a constant value
let b two = x + two;

x <- 1;

let c = b 2;

let isConsistent = a = c;


val mutable x : int = 1
val a : int = 2
val b : two:int -> int
val c : int = 3
val isConsistent : bool = false
```

Comment: If you are learning F#, why are you using `mutable`. Learning functional programming by carrying over the ideas of procedural and object-oriented languages, from my viewpoint, is a bad idea.

Comment: I don't want to mutate a on my own. I want 'a' to be a function returning x + 2

Comment: @checkThisOut so make it a function

Comment: Of interest: [What does this '()' notation mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17870937/1243762)

Comment: I agree, although unit arg isn't **strictly** needed here. We could have `let a _ = x + 2` ; but that's not really the same semantics ; former is a function returning x + 2 ; the latter would be a function discarding it's argument to return x + 2.

Comment: `let a = x + 2; // I want not to set a to a constant value` It is not a constant value, it is a [`bound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/let-bindings-%5Bfsharp%5D) value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your own comment you want `a` to be a **function returning x + 2**
Direct translation of that is :

```
let mutable x = 0

let a () = x + 2
let b two = x + two

x <- 1

let c = b 2

let isConsistent = a () = c // don't forget to call the function 'a'

(*
val mutable x : int = 1
val a : unit -> int
val b : two:int -> int
val c : int = 3
val isConsistent : bool = true
*)
```