# Problems with F# callstack in Visual Studio

Tags: f#, visual-studio-debugging

It looks that F# debugger doesn't work properly in VS 2015. Let me illustrate it on simple console program:

```
let f1 =
    printf "hello 1" 
    printf "hello 2" //1

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    f1 //2
    0
```

I set breakpoints on lines //1 and //2 and start the debugger.

First BP being hit is //1 while it should have been //2. Why is that?

Also at this moment I cannot navigate to the topmost level of the callstack. I.e. when I double click on the callstack entry which should have navigate me to line //2 VS tells me that "Source Not Available". Why is that?

These two problems doesn't stop me from debugging but nevertheless make pretty unhappy.

Comment: `f1` is a value, not a function.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17870937/180286

Comment: Ah, that was stupid! Thank you guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First BP being hit is //1 while it should have been //2. Why is that?

`f1` is not a function, it is a value of type unit. So its value is going to be constructed before `main` is called. You'll note that if you call `f1` multiple times, it only prints once because the value has been initialized. If you change `f1` to this:

```
let f1() = //etc
```

Then it will behave as you expect.

I suspect your callstack issue is because you are expecting `main` to be called before `f1`'s initializer, which isn't correct.