# Partially apply a function and dynamically call that function at runtime

Tags: f#, currying, partial-application

Using F#, if I partially apply a function like this:

```
let sleep x =  Async.Sleep x |> Async.RunSynchronously
let log date message= printfn "%s %s" date message
let getDate = DateTime.Now.ToString()
let logg = log getDate

logg "First"
sleep 1000
logg "Second"
sleep 1000
```

Prints:

```
30/11/2018 19:54:25 First
30/11/2018 19:54:25 Second
```

The call to getDate appears to be translated to an actual date in the new partial function it produces. Why is this, and is it possible to make it call getDate on each call to this log function?

Comment: Of interest: [What does this '()' notation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17872004/1243762)

Comment: cheers @GuyCoder so I have to declare all methods in the chain that use getDate with () after them, and call them accordingly to make them reevaluate when called, otherwise they become fixed variables. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so I have to declare all methods in the chain that use getDate with () after them, and call them accordingly to make them reevaluate when called, otherwise they become fixed variables. Is that right?

I'd put it the other way around: `let` always binds a value, but in `let getDate ()` or `let sleep x` case those values happen to be functions; they are basically equivalent to

```
let sleep = fun x -> Async.Sleep x |> Async.RunSynchronously

let getDate = fun () -> DateTime.Now.ToString()
```

Of course, this isn't really what happens if you examine bytecode, but "morally" it does. With these definitions

```
let sleep = fun x -> Async.Sleep x |> Async.RunSynchronously
let log = fun date message -> printfn "%s %s" date message
let getDate = fun () -> DateTime.Now.ToString()
let logg = fun x -> log (getDate ()) x

logg "First"
sleep 1000
logg "Second"
sleep 1000
```

you'll get the same output:

```
30/11/2018 19:59:40 First
30/11/2018 19:59:41 Second
```

Comment: I take it you did a copy and paste of his answer with the time. Time examples never come out the same twice and cause you think about them when doing unit testing.

Comment: Yes, of course. I considered mentioning "up to a different timestamp" but decided this was obvious enough (as was dependence on the locale).

Comment: You never know if someone is hiding a time machine in the garage.